# How to bind Query parameter into the datetime using room

Tags: java, android, android-room

I would like to bind a parameter into the datetime method of a sql query.
You can see below what I tried. I have tried enum too, but it seems enums are parsed by the name of enum and I can't give -7 days as a value to enum

The query i would like the code to produce looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Part where Timestamp > datetime('now' ,'-7 days')
```

Code#1

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Part where Timestamp >datetime('now' ,'-'+:days+'days')")
List<Part> getPastDays(int days);
```

Produces query#1

(is incorrect as it does not fetch the data)

```
SELECT * FROM Part where Timestamp >datetime('now' ,'-'+'7'+'days')
```

Code#2(Does not compile->error: Unused parameter: days)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Part where Timestamp >datetime('now' ,'- :days days')")
List<Part> getPastDays(int days);
```

Code#3

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Part where Timestamp >datetime('now' ,'-' /:days/ 'days')")
List<Part> getPastDays(int days);
```

Produces Query#3( is incorrect as does not return data)

```
SELECT * FROM Part where Timestamp >datetime('now' ,'-' /'7'/ 'days')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite SQL concatenate is || so :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Part where Timestamp >datetime('now' ,'-'||:days||' days')")
List<Part> getPastDays(int days);
```

as per *[The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of its operands](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators_and_parse_affecting_attributes).*